# How to assign translate language object at angular

Tags: angular, translate

```
lang: any = {};
```

I declare lang variable at LanguageService class.

```
  private getDefaultLanguage() {
let language = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
this.translate.setDefaultLang(language);

this.translate.getTranslation(language).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.lang = res;
});
console.log(this.lang);
```

}

Reassign value at lang variable from subscrible method, but lang is {}. i call getDefaultLangauge() function at constructor.

```
  constructor(private platform: Platform,private store: Storage,private translate: TranslateService){ 
this.checkLanguage(); 
this.getDefaultLanguage(); }
```

how to get data from subscrible to assign at lang variable

Comment: about you thought about using l18n from angular? to translate

Comment: You're already doing it. The problem is simply that you're printing its value **before** `this.lang = res;`has been executed.

Comment: how to assign at variable?.....

Comment: Again, you're already doing it. The problem is that you're printing `this.lang` long before `this.lang = res;` has been executed. Move your console.log immediately after `this.lang = res;`.